# Average value of $|x_1|$ over $n$-sphere

Tags: integration, geometry, surface-integrals

Suppose $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})$ are coordinates of points on [n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere). What's the average value of $|x_1|$?

Let $f(n)$ be such value for $n$-sphere. Mathematica [suggests](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-unit-sphere.nb) that

$$f(10)=\frac{63}{256}$$

What is the formula for general $n$?

**Motivation**: this predicts behavior of "Kaczmarz" method (also known as [ART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_reconstruction_technique)), which in one case is equivalent to repeatedly projecting a vector onto random hyperplane passing through origin. Value of $f$ indicates how far $w$ moves on average during each projection.

Comment: Hi! Interesting question—where did it come from?

Comment: @BrianTung was trying to understand behavior of "Kaczmarz" method (also known as [ART](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_reconstruction_technique)). When equations coefficients are isotropically distributed this method is equivalent to projecting current error onto random hyperplane passing  through origin. So it seems there's closed form solution for error norm after k steps, and it seems pretty far from bounds in Kaczmarz literature! (because they focus on worst case analysis)

Comment: @BrianTung btw, I liked your "high-dimensional weirdness" post. I've heard before that high-dimensional sphere is "spiky", but this made it conrete for me

Comment: Is that from my blog? I don't recall. Thanks! Anyway, not that I think it's a problem, but I think it does help people if you put the above background in the original post.

Comment: Also, I expanded out the expression in Jacob's answer; maybe that will be useful to you?

Comment: I think this $f$ tells only the expected distance of the first projection. On the next projection the point is no longer on the $n$-sphere but is somewhere inside it, or equivalently it is on an $n$-sphere of a smaller radius. That radius itself has a random value. It may be possible to estimate an average distance moved anyway, but it would need more than this question asks for.

Comment: @DavidK yes I now realize this is the wrong question for this application. What I needed to ask was how expected norm squared shrinks at each step, and it's (d-1)/d by using symmetry: at each step d dimensions contribute to norm squared, remove one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will use the hyperspherical coordinates outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates). Let $H^n$ be the $n$-hemisphere, obtained by only letting $\phi_{n-1}$ range from $0$ to $\pi$. In particular, the hypersurface area element $dA$ over $S^n$ or $H^n$ is given by
$$dA=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sin^{n-i}\phi_id\phi_i$$
while $x_n$ is given by
$$x_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sin\phi_i.$$
Then,
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{\text{Area}(S^n)}\int_{S^n}|x_n|dA=\frac{2}{\text{Area}(S^n)}\int_{H^n}x_ndA=\frac{2}{\text{Area}(S^n)}\int_{H^n} \prod_{i=1}^{n}\sin^{n+1-i}\phi_id\phi_i$$

However,
$$\text{Area}(S^{n+1})=2\int_{H^{n+1}} \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\sin^{n+1-i}\phi_id\phi_i=2\int_0^{\pi}\left(\int_{H^n} \prod_{i=1}^{n}\sin^{n+1-i}\phi_id\phi_i\right)d\phi_{n+1}=\pi \text{Area}(S^{n})f(n)$$

Hence, $$f(n)=\frac{\text{Area}(S^{n+1})}{\pi\text{Area}(S^{n})}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\pi^{1/2}\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2})}$$

Comment: It may be useful to the OP to point out that for odd $n$, this works out to $f(n) = \frac{2^n}{n!\pi}\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)!\right]^2$; and for even $n$, even more simply to $f(n) = 2^{-n}\binom{n}{n/2}$. So, for example, $f(10) = 2^{-10}\binom{10}{5} = \frac{252}{1024} = \frac{63}{256}$, as reported by Mathematica in the OP. Interestingly, this is the probability that a fair coin comes up heads exactly $5$ times in $10$ flips, from the binomial distribution.